# Logstash - parse array of JSON

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I'm trying to parse SendGrid Webhook events using Logstash. The issue is that Logstash's output is not an array of JSON, but only JSON. Square brackets are missing.

The reason I'm doing this is GeoIP location and UserAgent parsing for analytics.

I am posting to 127.0.0.1:3000, then I want to forward the output to 127.0.0.1:8080.
8080 is just a basic Express server which prints requests/responses and it sends final data to ElasticSearch.

This is the input:

```
[
  {
    "email": "email@domain.com",
    "event": "click",
    "ip": "8.8.8.8",
    "sg_event_id": "WS1wXXhERnefBsqEt5FSFA",
    "sg_message_id": "mk4Msf8nQvycsZIAHQPOrw.filter0321p1iad2-30191-5E686C57-5D.0",
    "timestamp": 1596484698,
    "url": "http://10.0.0.6/ServiceCenter/view",
    "url_offset": { "index": 1, "type": "html" },
    "useragent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
  }
]
```

This is the output:

```
{
  sg_event_id: 'WS1wXXhERnefBsqEt5FSFA',
  event: 'click',
  email: 'email@domain.com',
  sg_message_id: 'mk4Msf8nQvycsZIAHQPOrw.filter0321p1iad2-30191-5E686C57-5D.0',
  timestamp: 1596484698,
  useragent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko',
  ip: '8.8.8.8',
  url: 'http://10.0.0.6/ServiceCenter/view',
  url_offset: { index: 1, type: 'html' }
}
```

This is my config:

```
input {
  http {
    host => "127.0.0.1"
    port => "8080"
  }
}

filter {
  mutate {
    remove_field => [ "@version", "@timestamp", "headers", "host" ]
  }
}

output {
  http {
    http_method => "post"
    url => "http://127.0.0.1:3000"
  }
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So finally, I've found an workaround to do it using the `json_encode` filter.

1. Used ruby code to store keys and values to `@DATA[oldJSON]`
2. Used `json_encode` plugin on `@DATA[oldJSON]` and save the results to `@DATA[newJSON]`
3. Important: Set http output `format => message` and `content_type => "application/json; charset=UTF-8"`. Default is `text/plain` and we don't want this.
4. Set message value to `'[ %{[@DATA][newJSON]} ]'`

Config:

```
input {
  http {
    host => "127.0.0.1"
    port => "8080"
  }
}

filter {
  mutate {
    remove_field => [
      "@version",
      "@timestamp",
      "headers",
      "host"
    ]
  }
      ruby {
        code => '
            event.to_hash.each { |k,v|
                event.set("[@DATA][oldJSON][#{k}]", v)
    }
        '
  }
    json_encode {
      source => "[@DATA][oldJSON]"
      target => "[@DATA][newJSON]"
  }
  
}

output { 
  http {
    http_method => "post"
    url => "http://127.0.0.1:3000"
    format => message
    content_type => "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    message => '[ %{[@DATA][newJSON]} ]'
    }
  }
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    ip: '8.8.8.8',
    sg_message_id: 'mk4Msf8nQvycsZIAHQPOrw.filter0321p1iad2-30191-5E686C57-5D.0',
    url_offset: { type: 'html', index: 1 },
    sg_event_id: 'WS1wXXhERnefBsqEt5FSFA',
    email: 'email@domain.com',
    event: 'click',
    url: 'http://10.0.0.6/ServiceCenter/view',
    timestamp: 1596484698,
    useragent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko'
  }
]
```

Maybe somebody will find this useful.